# DashDB sync with Cloudant doesn't work

Tags: data-synchronization, cloudant, dashdb

I had a setup to sync data from Cloudant database into DashDB. Initially the setup and processes were working well. I keep the sync processes running after the setup. A few days later, I inserted a record into my Cloudant database, then I were expecting it being populated at DashDB automatically. But that didn't happen.

When I checked the sync process after above issue, I want to turn my sync process to 'Pause' and then 'Resume' it, a popup window shows me "Initialization in Progress" which blocks me to do anything about it.

Now, my sync processes are hanging in there, and data not being synced at all.

Any suggestions for solving the issue?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Cloudant does a continous transformation to dashdb if warehouse is created, may be the transformation hit an error, you can check if there is an error in the warehouser docs

Take a look inside the document inside the _warehouser database, and look for the warehouser_error_message to see if there is issue with transformation occurred.

Comment: Thanks, you are right when warehouse is created. But when warehouse is not created and user initially sync data with Cloudant from the DashDB, the issues are still existing.